# Abandoned mutex error occurs when runs window services?

Tags: c#, windows-services

This is the error:

```
System.Threading.AbandonedMutexException: The wait completed due to an abandoned mutex.
```

I have migrated code from windows application to windows service. Windows App runs absolutely fine on same machine but when i run Windows Service, i get this above error.

The app is basically initializes a bunch of settings and then read the bytes from database, writes the file on file system and then compresses the files using 7zip. Finally upload the file using ftp.

Any clue why am i getting this error?

Comment: Do you understand the conditions under which this error occurs?

Comment: Can you also post the stacktrace? Pretty hard to say anything with only that error.